# Own style of item

Tags: enumerate

I have a LaTeX document, where I have 50 items in an `enumerate` environment. I would like to create some own style of the items, which will look like the following:

On the top would will be a table with bullet and under the table would be a content of item.

Is this possible?

Example:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed felis risus, porttitor id lacus a, placerat fermentum elit. Aenean iaculis auctor magna sed sodales. Donec vitae elementum ligula. Vestibulum porta dui ac sapien vulputate, dignissim rutrum felis sagittis. Proin sit amet pretium lorem. Etiam cursus efficitur volutpat. Morbi id euismod tellus. Praesent sit amet scelerisque eros. Nullam id odio pretium, dignissim orci vitae, placerat dolor. Pellentesque venenatis libero risus, nec fermentum dui vehicula id. Nam consequat quam nisl, id eleifend est malesuada vel. Duis odio mi, lacinia eu consequat eget, sodales vel neque.
\end{enumerate}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create my own `tabenumerate` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{tabenumerate}
\newenvironment{tabenumerate}
  {\par\bigskip\setcounter{tabenumerate}{0}%
    \renewcommand{\item}{\par\medskip
    \noindent\refstepcounter{tabenumerate}%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
      \hline
      Number of item & \thetabenumerate \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \par\nobreak
    \medskip\noindent
  }}{\par\bigskip}
\begin{document}

Some text before \verb|tabenumerate|:

\begin{tabenumerate}
  \item First item
\end{tabenumerate}

Some text between \verb|tabenumerate|:

\begin{tabenumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
\end{tabenumerate}

Some final text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `enumitem` solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\@boxedlabel}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|l|p{5pt}|} 
    \hline
    Number of item & \arabic{#1} \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}

\def\boxedlabel#1{\@boxedlabel{#1}}
\AddEnumerateCounter*{\boxedlabel}{\@boxedlabel}{4}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=20pt,label={\boxedlabel*},labelwidth=60pt,labelindent=20pt]
\item 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed felis risus, porttitor id lacus a, placerat fermentum elit. Aenean iaculis auctor magna sed sodales. Donec vitae elementum ligula. Vestibulum porta dui ac sapien vulputate, dignissim rutrum felis sagittis. Proin sit amet pretium lorem. Etiam cursus efficitur volutpat. Morbi id euismod tellus. Praesent sit amet scelerisque eros. Nullam id odio pretium, dignissim orci vitae, placerat dolor. Pellentesque venenatis libero risus, nec fermentum dui vehicula id. Nam consequat quam nisl, id eleifend est malesuada vel. Duis odio mi, lacinia eu consequat eget, sodales vel neque.
\item Another one
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired result. The item box and the first line of the item contents are in the same line.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Yes, I've not read 'under' the table in the description

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) using a dedicated `tabenum` list environment giving the desired formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{newline}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-\labelsep][l]{#1}}

\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{  
  align=newline,
  label={\frame{%
    \protect\tabular{|l|l|} Number of item & \arabic*\protect\endtabular}%
  },
  leftmargin=0pt,
  itemindent=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabenum}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan pulvinar magna, eget suscipit ligula feugiat in. Nam iaculis egestas est sed dictum.
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan pulvinar magna, eget suscipit ligula feugiat in. Nam iaculis egestas est sed dictum.
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan pulvinar magna, eget suscipit ligula feugiat in. Nam iaculis egestas est sed dictum.
\end{tabenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}%
\newlist{framenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[framenum]{label =\makebox[\linewidth][l]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{-\fboxrule}\fbox{~Number of items\setlength\fboxsep{3pt} \fbox{\,\arabic*\,}}\vrule width0pt depth \topsep height 0pt}, wide=0pt}%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{framenum}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
\end{framenum}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]